# Cut polygons with overlapping clippers

Tags: clip, fme-form

I am trying to clip a layer with a polygon.
Some of my some clippers overlap each other. But it seem to only be the "aggregated" outer line that clip my layer. I want all layer to be clipped by all clippers, i.e. wherever a black line crosses polygon.

The image show an example. As seen on the picture the selected feature is only cut by the outermost border instead of both the elliptical polygons.

To do this I try to use the Clipper with the following parameters

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your workbench (or the relevant portion of it) and the parameters you've used in the transformers.

Comment: Yes, sorry if the question was incomplete. I hope my edit add enough valuable information to the relevant part of the workbench

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Clipper transformer (as designed) only clips a feature by the first Clipper that it finds. Once a feature is clipped it is passed through the Clipper:Inside output port regardless of what else clips it.

Here's my example (clipping parks with a 1000m buffer around firehalls):

[image]

What you need to do is use an AreaOnAreaOverlayer transformer, like so:

[image]

The issue there is that the clip part (in my case the buffer) also comes through the output port. So what you need to do is drop those features. Usually they have an attribute that you can identify them by.

In my case I just put a FeatureTypeFilter transformer down, filtered out the original FireHalls layer:

[image]

You'd just have to be careful what attributes you copy from the "clipper" to the "clippee" (otherwise you might filter out features you don't need).

Example workspace [available on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/730s1k14790i9n4/ClipperQuestion.fmwt?dl=1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful. Thanks for clearing out the specifics of how the clipper work. I can now move forward to the next step =)
Much appreciated